# Autocomplete for input parameters in a Python toolbox for ArcMap (or ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-pro, parameters, python-toolbox

Is there a way to get word completion to work for string parameter inputs in a Python toolbox? We are working with very long value lists (a few thousand entries per list) and scrolling the drop-down lists or the input window every time would be rather annoying. I'm currently working with ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1. (We plan to migrate to ArcGIS Pro (2.7.3) in the future.)

I tried using the `updateParameters(self, parameters)` function to update the filter list on the fly but it seems as if it's only invoked once the focus changes to another input parameter. I would like to avoid using an external library to listen to keystrokes because this could bear other issues.

Comment: I think this is unlikely to be possible using the provided functionality, given that there's not even any way to get notification that a checkbox in a list of checkboxes has been checked/unchecked until the user then clicks somewhere outside of the list (which is infuriating!).  My work-around is to have another boolean parameter with a title (eg, "Click here to update list") that prompts the user to click on it simply to invoke the desired outcome.  This could work to filter your lists, but would be a fairly poor user experience.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @son. I simply don't know wether there is a true solution to this in the scope of arcpy, so any workaround or tip is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is autocomplete but we have one input with a lot of Values and I have just defined it as an alphabetical list at the top of the python script as a global e.g.

```
 MList =['ALPINE','ARARAT','BALLARAT','BANYULE','BASS COAST']
```

and then used that list in the Python Toolbox in getParamterInfo:

```
        param3 = arcpy.Parameter(
          displayName="Select LGA Name",
          name ="PROP_LGA",
          datatype="GPString",
          parameterType="Required",
          direction="Input")
        param3.filter.type = 'ValueList'
        param3.filter.list = MList
```

Usually users will start typing the value and it seems to find the string ok.
Note: ArcGIS Pro 2.8.1